# grep command from python

Tags: python, shell, unix, grep

I used grep command from shell and it gave the result I wanted but when I run from my python script using os.popen it said

```
grep: SUMMARY:: No such file or directory
```

Normal grep command:

```
grep -A 12 -i "LOGBOOK SUMMARY:" my_folder/logbook.log
```

Python script

```
command="grep -A 12 -i LOGBOOK SUMMARY: my_folder/logbook.log"
result=os.popen(command)
```

Normal grep command gave the result I wanted. 
2nd one said no such file or directory

Comment: use the full path to the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose the search pattern within quotes:

```
command="grep -A 12 -i 'LOGBOOK SUMMARY:' my_folder/logbook.log"
```

How to diagnose such problems? Start from the error message:

> ```
> grep: SUMMARY:: No such file or directory
> ```

This error message tells that `grep` could not find a file named `SUMMARY:`.

The right question to ask is, why is `grep` looking for a file named `SUMMARY:`?
And the answer is that on the command line you executed,
somehow `SUMMARY:` is considered a filename:

```
command="grep -A 12 -i LOGBOOK SUMMARY: my_folder/logbook.log"
```

Of course! That's what would happen if you executed that command in the shell:

```
grep -A 12 -i LOGBOOK SUMMARY: my_folder/logbook.log
```

Here, the shell will split the command line on spaces,
and pass to `grep` 3 arguments, `LOGBOOK`, `SUMMARY:` and `my_folder/logbook.log`.
The first argument, `LOGBOOK` is used as the pattern to search for,
and all remaining arguments are taken as filenames to search in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Usually people give the solution but the way you explained. Awsome!!